# Futex based locking mechanism

Tags: linux, synchronization, locking, centos, futex

Somebody can tell me an example of using locking mechanism based on futex? (for muticore x86 CPU, CentOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pthreads' mutexes are implemented using futexes on recent versions of Linux. [Pthreads](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html) is the standard C threading API on Linux, and is part of the Posix standard, so you can easily port your program to other Unix-like systems. You should avoid using futexes directly unless you have very unusual needs, because they're very hard to use correctly - use pthreads, or a higher-level, language-specific API (which will almost certainly use pthreads itself).

Comment: What about latest version of CentOS 5.5? Is Pthreads' mutexes on CentOS 5.5 are implemented using futexes?
Thanks

Comment: Futexes have been used by pthreads on all distributions of Linux since about 2004, when 2.6-series kernels were adopted. That includes CentOS. I don't understand why you need to worry about them, though... they're largely an implementation detail.

Comment: because I need to use locks in very time-critical path of the server application (the place where all data passed through).
I think that is better to use some "fast" locking mechanism...

Comment: @Dima: You shouldn't assume that pthreads mutexes are too slow until you've tried them. And futexes aren't really a complete locking mechanism, they're just the kernel part of it. You still need to write some assembly language in order to use them as a lock, which is very, very hard to get right. I recommend writing your program with pthreads mutexes, which actually are very fast. If your program is too slow, then try making the locks finer-grained, so that different threads don't need all need to use the same lock at the same time. Although this sounds hard, it's easier than using futexes.

Comment: @Doug - I know this is an older post, but futex has never required asm from the best I can tell. http://people.redhat.com/drepper/futex.pdf was writen in ,04 and didn't even call for asm at that point when they were still relativly new.

Comment: And generaly speaking, the ability to code a futex is a matter of compatancy in C. If one able to do multi threaded pthreads coding they should be assumed capable of using futex. Really.

Comment: All due respect, "you should not use it" is not a real answer to "how to use something".  Not to mention you exaggerated the difficulty to use futex.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/avsm/ipc-bench. They use futex in shared memory pipe implementation.

Specifically, you can check [this code](https://github.com/avsm/ipc-bench/blob/master/mempipe_thr.c#L143-L185).

Answer (score 0):

working example: pthreads mutex use futex locks.

code example: These were made within months of this post in '10 but are still up-to-date.

http://meta-meta.blogspot.com/2010/11/linux-threading-primitives-futex.html
https://github.com/lcapaldo/futexexamples

use case example: IPC and inter-process synchronization are the only example of why one should use a futex in userspace. pthread mutexes will work for multi-thread except for extreme cases, but multi-process is lacking in high performance locking mechanisms as well as lock types.